# What is this insect in a cocoon climbing a web?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I found this thing hanging from the framework of my garage yesterday:

[image]

The size of the object in the picture was about .75 inches tall by maybe a quarter inch wide. This was taken yesterday in a suburb of Jacksonville, Florida, US in late evening (8:30 pm?).

He was (apparently) using his mouth-parts to draw in what appeared to be a strand of spiderweb, and in about 10 minutes had drawn himself upward, towards the top of the garage framework, a total distance of about two feet.

An additional question would be what is that he's in, a cocoon? a piece of bark or something being used like a hermit crab uses a scavenged shell?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You're much more likely to get reasonable answers if you remove the silliness from your question and use an informative title. Also make sure you adhere to the [species identification guidelines](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info).

Comment: I edited the post to remove the alien nonsense the OP included. I opted to edit the post so to avoid attracting further downvotes given that it's an interesting specimen and the post follows the [tag:species-identification] guidelines otherwise. @Chowzen, in the future please keep your posts professional and to the point. Ideally, when asked to edit your post, you should [edit] on your own to avoid closure. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is, probable, a Psychidae (Lepidoptera), commonly known as bagworms. They build those "bags" with pieces of wood, twigs and leaves, and they protect them from predators and parasitoids. One possible species for Florida is this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evergreen_bagworm